# Pandas DataFrame, Haversine function of 4 lat/long columns to new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, haversine

With this DataFrame I am trying to take the start lat/long and end lat/long to create a new column that shows the Haversine distance between the two

```
    import pandas as pd
import haversine as hs

d = {'start_lat': [35.9946, 29.4400,29.4400 ], 'start_long': [-81.7266,-98.4590, -98.4590 ],
     'end_lat': [ 36.430124, 29.819364, 29.273085], 'end_long': [-81.179483,-99.142791,-98.836360]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I can get the Haversine function to work as a standalone function:

```
def hav(x, y):
    return hs.haversine(x, y)

start_coord=(35.9946, -81.7266)
end_coord=(36.430124, -81.179483)

print(hav(start_coord, end_coord))
```

To try and create new haversine column for the df I have first created two new coordinate columns

```
df['start_coord'] = list(zip(df.start_lat, df.start_long))
df['end_coord'] = list(zip(df.end_lat, df.end_long))
df
```

I then try and apply the function in creation of new column but I get a **value error:** too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
df["Haversine_dist"] = hav(df["start_coord"],df["end_coord"])
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an apply with a lambda here to work on single rows. When you input `df['start_coord']` you're using the whole series.

```
df["Haversine_dist"] = df.apply(lambda x: hav(x["start_coord"], x["end_coord"]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is working, but could you please help my understanding, why is it that this simple adder function does work for the method I put in my questions but the haversine func doesn't? 

`def adder(x, y):
    return(x + y)
df["arbitrary_sum"]= adder(df["start_lat"], df["start_long"])`

Comment: You're welcome. As for your second question, I don't know for sure, but I would guess that it works because pandas has native awareness of how to sum columns and it's smart enough to call one of the correct series methods. Whereas, pandas has no way to easily understand what haversine is or what it's supposed to do. Could be an interesting new SO question. : )